# pop up messages once aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

currently I am facing a problem with pop up msgs.

The messages should prompt out first time click on a NEXT button.

when we go to the next pages and back to the previous pages, and click on the same NEXT button, the pop up msgs should not appear.

how can i fix this?

This is button code

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click1" Text="Next" Width="100px" />
```

This is the function() for my clickedOnce

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.document.onload = function()
        {
            var clickedOnce = false;

            Button1.Button1_Click1 = function ()
            {

               if(!confirm('Please make sure the employee particulars and reporting line details are correct before save. \nClick OK to save and continue if all details are correct.\nClick Cancel and contact HR Admin if details appear is not up to date.'))return false;
                    clickedOnce = true;

                }
            }
</script>
```

Thank you. your kindness and help much appreciated.

Comment: try putting the variable `clickedOnce` outside your function.

Comment: ive tried, but the msgs still show up every time the next button is clicked

Comment: Moving the 'clickedOnce' variable out of the JavaScript function won't make any difference if the user moves out of the current page and coming back to it. All global variables (page specific) will be refreshed/ initialised each time the page loads.

Comment: ohh. then how should i prevent the code being initialized when the page loads for the second or more time?

Comment: Please see my answer below for some ideas to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you only want to run it once, could you give the user a cookie that lasts until the browsing session is over when they fist click the button? If they have the cookie, then you could skip over the line of code that you only want to run once.

Comment: how should i use cookie. i have never use before

Comment: It's a thing in Javascript, and [http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) could explain it better than I ever could :P

Comment: haha thanks for the efforts btw. ill try to figure it out then.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work at all. The main issue is how you try to catch click event.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click1" Text="Next" />
```

It means that `Button1_Click1` function runs at **server**. No client-side event occurs. To do something on client side you have to add `onclientclick="someFunction()"` to your button declaration.
OK, you add this. Now go to javascript.

```
function someFunction(){
   var clickOnce = getCookie('clickOnce');
   //Look @Darkrifts comment (link) how to do it.
   //Just in case I reproduce the link http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
   if(!clickOnce || confirm('blah blah')){
      document.cookie = 'clickOnce=1';
      //no need to return anything
   }
   //if a visitor doesn't click "ok" then the popup appear again
}
```

It is also possible to set `Session["clickOnce"] = true;` on server side and use it from `Page_Load` server side handler but it may not work if a visitor return to the page using browser `Back` button.

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e){
   Session["clickOnce"] = true;
   //more code
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
   if(Session["clickOnce"] != true)
     Button1.OnClientClick = "someFunction()";
   else
     Button1.OnClientClick = "";
   //more code
}
```

Comment: if (Session["clickOnce"] != true)  this code produce error that != cannot be operand for bool. so i change to integer. but then the same error appear again

Comment: btw thanks for your example and efforts. Ill try my best to fix this

Comment: The fix is obvious but you have to find it by your own.

Comment: Try this bool.Parse(Session["clickOnce"].ToString()) != true But, you should try to figure it your self as @AlexKudryashev mentioned :)

Comment: And, it's better to check for null and empty string in the session variable if you are planning to use this session variable somewhere else. if(Session["clickOnce"] != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["clickOnce"].ToString()) == false && bool.Parse(Session["clickOnce"].ToString()) != true)

Comment: It is enough to check `if(Session["clickOnce"] != null`. No other value is expected. In any case, the first option (set cookie) is better. I explained why in my answer. Follow the link and do your best. It is not a kind of Rocket Science.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in multiple ways. You need to select the most efficient approach for your need. First of all you need to understand the [ASP.Net page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), [persisting information between pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx) and [ViewState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).

**In a nutshell...**

Whenever your page reloads all elements (including JavaScript variables, be it global or local variables) in your page get's initialised. And then a feature in ASP.Net comes into play. I.e. `ViewState`. If this is set to true in page level or for each control it'll persist information of the controls in the page (depends on how you set this). But, this is page specific.

And, you could persist information between pages using following approaches

- Query string
- Session variables
- Cache
- Form posts
- Cookies
- Data store (e.g. text, xml or any other database/ data store)

Before you use any of the above mentioned approaches you must think about your requirement. @Alex Kudryashev came up with a good example while I was writing this answer. Let me know if you need example with a different approach or any clarifications.

Comment: i have try Alex's answer, but I got an error for that. since I am not so familiar with cookies. if its not burdening you, can you assist me with the example. thank you sam!

Comment: You have to vote for answers that are useful in resolving your issue and accept the most appropriate answer. This is how SO works. Cheers!

Comment: I'm still working on resolving the issue. Wait up. of course ill be voting the most useful answer.